# Django Error while saving avatar : expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: django, django-allauth, avatar

there is an error on cleaned_data['avatar'] (in forms.py) : expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

this error appears when I sign in with an image for avatar.

I m using Django-allauth but not used to it.... So I add an avatar field which appears in sign_in form but I've the error when submitting.

this is my code: models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


def get_path_name(instance, filename):
    path = 'media/avatar/'
    name = instance.user.id + "-" + instance.user.email
    path = path + name
    return path

# custom User model
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to= get_path_name, blank=True, null=True)
```

my form:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
from django import forms

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'avatar')

    def clean_avatar(self):
        avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']

        try:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)

            # validate dimensions
            max_width = max_height = 100
            if w > max_width or h > max_height:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Please use an image that is '
                    '%s x %s pixels or smaller.' % (max_width, max_height))

            # validate content type
            main, sub = avatar.content_type.split('/')
            if not (main == 'image' and sub in ['jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'gif', 'png']):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please use a JPEG, '
                                            'GIF or PNG image.')

            # validate file size
            if len(avatar) > (20 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Avatar file size may not exceed 20k.')

        except AttributeError:
            """
            Handles case when we are updating the user profile
            and do not supply a new avatar
            """
            pass

        return avatar

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'avatar')
```

my template:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}

{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

my settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

I've check that migrations works as I can see field in database. But of course empty du to previous error.

I've another issue is that avatar field does not appears in /admin/change/user but I put the field in CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

and this is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

CustomUser = get_user_model()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'avatar']

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

error traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/

Django Version: 3.1.2
Python Version: 3.7.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap4',
 'crispy_forms',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'accounts',
 'home']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 215, in dispatch
    return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 81, in dispatch
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 193, in dispatch
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 103, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 177, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/Users//hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 374, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/Users/hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 395, in _clean_fields
    value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
  File "/Users//hima/accounts/forms.py", line 15, in clean_avatar
    w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)
  File "/Users/hima/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/images.py", line 47, in get_image_dimensions
    file = open(file_or_path, 'rb')

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: add your complete error traceback

Comment: just shared it...

Comment: seems like `self.cleaned_data['avatar']` is returning the value **`None`**

Comment: yes but don t know why...

Comment: in self.data['avatar']  I've a string value is  signature.png

Comment: but in self.cleaned_data['avatar'] I ve none